# Using QMessageBox to debug during QGIS plugin development?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plugin in QGIS 3.4 and usually I debug with QMessageBox. Everything is running ok until I debug a list and the result was this one.

[image]

What happens?

Answer (score 1):

The image I am seeing doesn't have any text.  Is that expected?  What if you try to debug using a python print function.  The output should appear in the python console in Qgis.  To open the python console in Qgis go to the Plugins menu and click Python Console.

```
print some_variable
print "some message"
```

Comment: Using print can crash a multithreaded Qt application like QGIS and should be avoided. Use QGIS' logging functions instead.